# Initialize JAXBContext in a post construct method

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am using JAXB to convert an xml into a java object. Our application is event driven. When some event happens a method in the Parser class is called. We will receive the xml as a byte array.

Since its very costly to create a JAXBContext every time when the event is fired and even meaningless.

So I tried to shift this code to a post construct method. Then I realized JAXBConext.newInstance(Class) throws a JAXBException. Is it a good idea to put the initialization code here? If the creation fails due to some reason there is no meaning in processing the events now.

Is there any other approach?

Comment: Maybe you can initialize the context in the parser listener constructor.

Comment: I don't think constructor is also best. Its the same. Ok, I think there are not other options. I think my problem is to take a decision when an exception happens rather than how to initialize it. We decided to log the exceptions and do nothing on event

Comment: If you initialize it in the constructor you can get the exception in a "setup" phase.

Comment: What is "setup" phase? Do you mean initialization phase? If you mean setup to initialization then it doesnt matter for me because irrespective of the exception I should be able to create an object of the listener class. Or else the deployment will fail. We dont want to fail the deployment.